# Could NOT find Protobuf (missing: Protobuf_INCLUDE_DIR)

Tags: cmake, ubuntu-16.04, ros

I am trying to `catkin_make` in my catkin workspace, but I get the following error

> CMake Deprecation Warning at gazebo_ros_demos/gazebo_tutorials/CMakeLists.txt:1
> (cmake_minimum_required):   Compatibility with CMake < 2.8.12 will be
> removed from a future version of   CMake.
>
> Update the VERSION argument  value or use a ... suffix to
> tell   CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older
> versions.
>
> -- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
> -- Found Boost: /usr/include (found suitable version "1.58.0", minimum required is "1.40.0") found components: thread signals system
> filesystem program_options regex iostreams date_time chrono atomic
> CMake Error at
> /usr/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230
> (message):   Could NOT find Protobuf (missing: Protobuf_INCLUDE_DIR)
> Call Stack (most recent call first):
> /usr/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:594
> (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
> /usr/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindProtobuf.cmake:646
> (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/gazebo/gazebo-config.cmake:114
> (FIND_PACKAGE)   gazebo_ros_demos/gazebo_tutorials/CMakeLists.txt:11
> (find_package)
>
> -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred! See also "/home/ashwin/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log". See also
> "/home/ashwin/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
> Makefile:5582: recipe for target 'cmake_check_build_system' failed
> make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1 Invoking "make
> cmake_check_build_system" failed

This issue came up when I tried to update my cmake to 3.20. I am fairly new to Ubuntu. Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same issue (on ubuntu 18.04). Installing the following packages resolved the issue for me:

```sh
sudo apt-get install libprotobuf-dev protobuf-compiler
```

These are similar to the packages mentioned by K.S., but with those packages I got the same error as Ashwin mentioned in the comments on K.S.'s answer.